# Spring Boot OAuth2 password login via basic auth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I have a Spring Boot application with multiple http security configurations. Each of them is using external Keycloak.

- API URLs are using Bearer token authentication
- swagger URLs are using authentication code flow (user interaction needed)
- URLs that authenticates via Basic Auth

First 2 works fine but I can't get basic auth configuration running. For that I would like to use ****OAuth2 grant type password****.

My `application.properties` oauth2 configuration:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak2.client-id=${KEYCLOAK_RESOURCE}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak2.client-secret=${KEYCLOAK_RESOURCE_CLIENT_SECRET}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak2.authorization-grant-type=password
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak2.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak2.issuer-uri=${keycloak.auth-server-url}/realms/${keycloak.realm}
```

My configuration for Basic auth endpoints looks like this:

```java
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ProcessConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        public static class OAuth2PasswordAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

            private final OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient;
            
            private final OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> userService;
            
            private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
            
            private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper = ((authorities) -> authorities);

            public OAuth2PasswordAuthenticationProvider(
                    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient,
                    OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> userService,
                    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
                super();
                this.accessTokenResponseClient = accessTokenResponseClient;
                this.userService = userService;
                this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

                if (!(authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)) {
                    return null;
                }

                final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePassword = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

                final String username = (String) usernamePassword.getPrincipal();
                final String password = (String) usernamePassword.getCredentials();

                final String registrationId = "keycloak2";
                final ClientRegistration keycloak2 = clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(registrationId);
                
                final OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest request = new OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest(keycloak2, username, password);
                final OAuth2AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = accessTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(request);
                final OAuth2User oauth2User = this.userService.loadUser(new OAuth2UserRequest(
                        keycloak2, accessTokenResponse.getAccessToken(), accessTokenResponse.getAdditionalParameters()));
                final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = this.authoritiesMapper
                        .mapAuthorities(oauth2User.getAuthorities());
                final OAuth2AuthenticationToken authenticationResult = new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(oauth2User, mappedAuthorities, registrationId);
                return authenticationResult;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class authentication) {
                return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/v1/process/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Client()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
        
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient() {
            return new DefaultPasswordTokenResponseClient();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public OAuth2PasswordAuthenticationProvider oAuth2PasswordAuthenticationProvider(
                OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2PasswordGrantRequest> accessTokenResponseClient,
                OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> userService,
                ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
            
            // Here I'm missing userService
            return new OAuth2PasswordAuthenticationProvider(accessTokenResponseClient, userService, clientRegistrationRepository);
        }
}
```

I've got `Parameter 1 of method oAuth2PasswordAuthenticationProvider in com.example.config.SecurityConfig$ProcessConfigurationAdapter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService' that could not be found.`
I thought it would autowire based on configuration in `application.properties` but no. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

Password grant flow is deprecated. Don't try to use it.

Authorization-code flow is a protocol between client and authorization-server to authenticate users and acquire access-token for client to act on behalf of those users. It is to be used client side (Angular, React, Vue, Flutter, etc. or Spring modules with Thymeleaf or other sever-side rendering) and has nothing to do with REST API.

To authenticated **trusted** programs (server-side applications that you can trust to keep a secret actually secret), you should use client-credentials flow to acquire access-tokens (for the client itself, not on behalf of the user). If you write such Spring services, configure it as OAuth2 client with client credentials.

In both cases from the resource-server point of view (the Spring REST API documented with Swagger), this doesn't make a difference: requests come with an Authorization header containing a Bearer access-token, and this is what you should build security-context from. [Sample there](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers).